# Sass.js @imports Don't Work

Tags: javascript, sass

Was looking through this solution:

https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/

And after much trial and error I got it to work when converting a scss string that looks something like this:

```
var testScss1 = '$testColour1: #ff0000' + 
'.box { color: $testColor1 }';

var sassWithVariables = new Sass();

sassWithVariables.compile(testScss1, function (result) {
    // result.text is defined and converts perfectly
});
```

But this example with an import to a file called _demo.scss, will not work and I want to throw my chair across the room!

```
var testScss2 = '@import "_demo";';

var sassWithImports = new Sass();

sassWithImports.compile(testScss2, function (result) {
    /*
    get this error:

    ERROR Error: file to import not found or unreadable: _demo
       Current dir: 
        on line 1 of stdin
   >> @import "_demo";
  */
});
```

Comment: Was `_demo.scss` previously made available via `writeFile()`? The [docs](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/) imply that this is required (per the "Working With Files" section).

Comment: @PaulRoub not it was not. I tried it since I posted this. And that seems to register it. I thought writeFile for some reason would write to disk, which I didn't want to do.

Comment: Are you on OS X 10.11? I'm looking for a solution too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045806/is-el-capitans-rootless-breaking-old-grunt-configs

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand sass.js, it creates a virtual sass-file : a variable in the DOM. 
It will not use a real file from your filesystem.

- If you just want to use virtual files, all is documented on:
  https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/#working-with-files .
- If you want to use a file from you filesystem, you have to make an ajax-call to get the file. When that's done, you can place it in the virtual
  file and run sass.js

This is how to do it:

1. Your server doesn't know the mime-type of .SCSS and .MEM, so you'll have to state it. 
    
   On a windows-server, you can do it in your web.config (in the root of your folder) like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
     </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mem" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".scss" mimeType="text/css" />
         </staticContent>
      </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

   I don't know how to do it on other environments, but i'm sure it won't be too hard to find.
2. Write the javascript to get the file, and create it as a virtual file. 
   The following code works with jquery 1.8.3 and you must run this on a server. 
   In this example i'm getting 2 sassfiles instead of just one. I don't know what you want to do with the generated css, but i assume you want to put it somewhere on the page to affect your html.

   ```
   var myexternalfileOne = ''; 
   var myexternalfileTwo = ''; 
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       $.when(
            $.ajax({
                url: "/sass/_utilities.scss", dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                   // the contents of the real file is now put into the empty var:
                    myexternalfileOne = data;
                }
            }),
            $.ajax({
                url: "/sass/_styling.scss", dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                   // the contents of the real file is now put into the empty var:
                    myexternalfileTwo = data;
                }
            })
        ).then( function(){
           // all files are loaded and put into vars. Finally, we initiate SASS.JS: 
            var sass = new Sass();
            sass.writeFile('_virtualfileOne.scss', myexternalfileOne);
            sass.writeFile('_virtualfileTwo.scss', myexternalfileTwo);
            sass.compile('@import "_virtualfileOne"; @import "_virtualfileTwo";', function(result) {
                // SASS.JS has created css out of the sass-files from your filesystem. 
                // If we want it to affect our page, we just put it somewhere, in this case, we put it before a div#uniqueid
                $('div#uniquediv').prepend('<style>' + result.text+ '</style>'); 
            });
        });
   });
   ```