# Is 'El Capitan's' rootless breaking old grunt configs?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

After migrating to El Capitan, it seems users are experiencing an issue with grunt installations, possibly related to the rootless changes of El Capitan. In particular, running the grunt --force command results in EPERM errors. The workflow is as follows:

Assuming npm has been installed, navigate to the grunt directory with package.json and gruntfile.js and invoke grunt:

```
grunt --force
```

Example Gruntfile.js file contents:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // All configuration goes here 
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {
            // Configuration for concatenating files goes here.
            dist: {
                src: [
                        '../js/libs/owl.carousel.js',
                        '../js/libs/jquery.actual.js',
                        '../js/libs/chosen.jquery.js',
                        '../js/libs/jquery.parallax.js',
                        '../js/src/common.js'  
                ],
                dest: '../js/pro/global.js',
            },
        },

        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: '../js/pro/global.js',
                dest: '../js/pro/global.min.js',
            },
        },


        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '../img/src/',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: '../img/pro/'
                }]
            }
        },

        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {              
                    sassDir: '../sass',
                    cssDir: '../css',
                    fontsDir: '../fonts',
                    imagesDir: '../img/',
                    images: '../img/',
                    javascriptsDir: '../js/pro',
                    //environment: 'development',
                    outputStyle: 'compressed',
                    relativeAssets: true,
                    httpPath: '.',
                }
            },
        },

        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['../js/**/**.js'],
                tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
                options: {
                    spawn: true,
                },
            },
            images: {
                files: ['../img/src/**.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                tasks: ['imagemin'],
                options: {
                    spawn: true,
                }
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['../**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev'],
            }

        },

        svgstore: {
            defaults: {
                options: {
                    prefix : 'icon-',
                },
                files: {
                    '../img/svg-defs.svg': ['../img/svg/*.svg']
                }
            }
        },


    });

    // Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svgstore');

    // Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', /*'imagemin',*/ 'compass', 'svgstore', 'watch']);

};
```

Example package.json file contents:

```
{
"name": "Call Me Maybe",
"version": "0.2.0",
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.4",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.4",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-svgstore": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

The resulting EPERM errors are as follows:

```
Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
Warning: Unable to write "../js/pro/global.js" file (Error code: EPERM). Used --force, continuing.

Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
Warning: Unable to write "../js/pro/global.min.js" file (Error code: EPERM). Used --force, continuing.

Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh: compass: command not found. Used --force, continuing.
Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Used --force, continuing.

Running "svgstore:defaults" (svgstore) task
Warning: Unable to write "../img/svg-defs.svg" file (Error code: EPERM). Used --force, continuing.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Interestingly, Ruby and Compass are also installed, so it does align with the theory of the rootless unable to write to folders issues, **but how can the dependency cores be moved elsewhere** (i.e. /usr/local/bin) **so this isn't an issue?**

During the El Capitan Betas, some users suggested enabling root via terminal - though this seemingly no longer works, as the error persists and /usr/bin folder still doesn't allow for permission changes.

Comment: I had a bunch of issues with global gem installations after el capitan and had to reinstall them again to the `/usr/local/bin` directory with `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass`. But I don't recognize your errors. Is it possible any node dependencies are installed globally in the root?

Comment: Possibly, I did use that `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass` but didn't solve the issue. I do find that when running `grunt -v --force` everything runs fine, but when each file goes to write, it can't write, for example `Warning: Unable to write "../img/svg-defs.svg" file (Error code: EPERM). Used --force, continuing.`

Comment: `brew install node` will put npm in `usr/local/bin` so you can forget about permission troubles. I also recommend a reboot to recovery and a `csrutil disable` to turn off SIP. Especially if you have formulae that reside in `usr/local/sbin` DISCLAIMER: I recommend disabling SIP if you are pretty security conscious and I'm not responsible for an accidental `sudo rm -rf /.` check `brew install safe-rm` if you want to be really careful. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those running into the same issue, I had to eliminate the use of binaries installed to the path: /usr/bin, and reinstall after updating the path /usr/local/bin. Ruby tended to be the primary culprit. Because I was struggling with locating all my ruby installs, I ended up installing rbenv to manage my ruby versions.

The following terminal commands may be helpful in identifying your problematic paths:

```
which ruby
gem environment
gem uninstall [insert gem name here]
[google how to set your paths to /usr/local/bin... (will be in a hidden file)]
gem install [insert gem name here]
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing non-system software on /usr/bin is a bad move, and is now prohibited in El Capitan, and with good reason.

I am not familiar with grunt, but if you can get to use /usr/local/bin instead then probably everything works.

Comment: I agree, hence I've bolded my portion of the question that asks 'how' can they be moved elsewhere so that isn't an issue.

 I would also like to make it clear that I did not down vote your answer, so please do not downvote my question in spite.