# Sass.js compile Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I need compile whole bootstrap and some few other scss files on client. I'm looking for some js compiler for scss I'm found this one https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/. I tried it looks good, but I don't understan How can I work with files. Documentation wasn't helpful for me. 
I need compile many files, I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33154233/8653863, but it's not convient way how to work with files if you have more then 10 file.

In Less js you can link your .less to  and thats it. Is there similiar option for sass js?

PS: I asking for solution, not for reason why I shloudn't do that.

I'm looking for a sample how to us scss bootstrap with sass.js

Let's say I have file structure

- Web

  - Content

    - Bootstrap
      -all bootstrap .scss
    - MyScssFiles
      -few my scss files
    - site.scss - import of all files include bootstrap
  - Scripts

    - sass.js
  - index.html

How should I use sass js to work with this?